How to filter products by their grouped tag id in prisma
Here is my products table,
model TagGroup {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String?

  tags Tag[]

  @@map("tagGroups")
  @@schema("public")
}

model Tag {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String?

  group   TagGroup @relation(fields: [groupId], references: [id])
  groupId Int

  productTags  ProductTags[]
  categoryTags CategoryTags[]

  @@map("tags")
  @@schema("public")
}

model ProductTags {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int

  tag   Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
  tagId Int

  @@map("productTags")
  @@schema("public")
}

Now I have the filter array like [ [ 44 ], [ 38 ], [ 39, 40 ] ], Please check the attachment to understand the format for this array, its like tags are separated by group id.
Please check out this attachment
Now I want to filter the products by their tag group.Check this website to see what I exactly want. So applying these filter none of the products should not return, intel will return if I select intel, 4 and Intel LGA2011 and AMD should only return only amd and 2 is selected.
